# Php Imagick Crop Image From Variable Center Point

Tags: php, angularjs, image, math, imagick

I'm building an implementation of [Croppie](https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/) as an AngularJS directive to provide a UI for users to crop their profile images.

My backend is PHP, and I need a way for the UI selections to be reflected in the server-side manipulations.

I have a 150 by 150 square in the center of my image, as the linked Croppie example similarly shows. As you can see however, you can move and scale the image around, which means cropping *from center* in Imagick wouldn't always work depending on how the user positions their image around the center point.

I know I can scale the image and then crop from the center in Imagick, but how do I account for the fact that the image will be translated as well?

When I move the image around in my implementation, I get the following data-points to parse and send to the server:

`{transform: "translate3d(-60px, -121px, 0px) scale(1)"}`

This shows for example, that the image has been shifted along the X and Y axis, and has not been scaled. How do I shift the center of the image accordingly in Imagick?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

I see these commands: [Imagick::cropThumbnailImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.cropthumbnailimage.php) and [Imagick::cropImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.cropimage.php) is there some way to kind of combine them where the cropped area remains in the center as the image is scaled and the image can be shifted on the x or y axis?

**EDIT 2**

Well, I figured out I need to use a combination of [Imagick::cropImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.cropthumbnailimage.php) and [Imagick::scaleImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.scaleimage.php) but I can't figure out the correct math to send to the server.

I'm attaching an image so you can see what I mean, I'm getting very close but the crop is off on some images:

[image: Cropping An Image]

My HTML is like so:

```
<div class="viewBox">
<img class="bigTuna">
<div class="enclosedCrop small"></div>
<div class="overlay small"></div>
</div>
```

The image you are seeing, which I want to crop using `.encloseCrop.small` which is the circle, is `.bigTuna`.

I am using the following to calculate the offset of the image (which I can drag around the `.encloseCrop.small`) relative to the scale of the image (`.bigTuna`). The offset of `.encloseCrop.small` is `.viewBox`, and the image takes up the entire `.viewBox` with a `max-width: 100%;`

Because the image has a `width`, `naturalWidth` and `getBoundingClientRect().width` (*and respective properties for heigh*t) I'm unsure how to accomplish this where I can send to Imagick just an `X` and `Y` for the `cropImage()` arguments.

This is the closest I have gotten:

```
var Xvalue = (angular.element(".enclosedCrop")[0].offsetLeft + ( -1 * $scope.matrixobject.x )) * ((angular.element('.bigTuna')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width/angular.element('.bigTuna')[0].width)*(angular.element('.bigTuna')[0].naturalWidth/angular.element('.bigTuna')[0].width));
var Yvalue = (angular.element(".enclosedCrop")[0].offsetTop + ( -1 * $scope.matrixobject.y ))  * ((angular.element('.bigTuna')[0].getBoundingClientRect().height/angular.element('.bigTuna')[0].height)*(angular.element('.bigTuna')[0].naturalHeight/angular.element('.bigTuna')[0].height));
```

The bounding width divided by the width is the scale factor, but I need to account for the natural width somehow as well I believe. The issue is that the image you see in the modal where the `Croppie`-like directive resides already is scaled because it isn't the natural dimensions. On top of that, I'm scaling this (already) scaled image again using CSS transforms.

But when I send the image to PHP, it doesn't know about this. I just receives the natural dimensions and wants to know how to crop it. I need that crop to reflect the UI crop.

`$scope.matrixobject.x` is the value of the transform of the image, in this case, the amount of pixels it was translated left. I can get all these values just fine, I just don't know what equation is actually the correct one utilizing said values.

**EDIT 3:**

I've refined my equation like so, but this equation, although it makes the most sense to me, gives me completely off crops.

```
var Xvalue = (angular.element(".enclosedCrop")[0].offsetLeft + ( -1 * $scope.matrixobject.x )) * (angular.element('.bigTuna')[0].naturalWidth/angular.element('.bigTuna')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width);
var Yvalue = (angular.element(".enclosedCrop")[0].offsetTop + ( -1 * $scope.matrixobject.y ))  * (angular.element('.bigTuna')[0].naturalHeight/angular.element('.bigTuna')[0].getBoundingClientRect().height);
```

The equation first tries to get the **offset** of the 150 x 150 circle (`.enclosedCrop`) from from the top and left of the image's container:

In the case of the height, this looks like so:

`angular.element(".enclosedCrop")[0].offsetTop + ( -1 * $scope.matrixobject.y )`

The first part of this excerpt of the equation gets the offsetTop, which would remain constant as `.enclosedCrop` itself is stationary in the center of the container. `$scope.matrixobject.y` is the transform of the image around the container, and by inverting it, we can get the transform needed if instead the `.enclosedCrop` moved around the image. By adding this to the offset, we know where the crop is happening on the image.

However, the **offset** and transforms are relative to the size of the image in the container (`max-width:100%`) which means that they need to be **scaled** to reflect the natural size of the image and any transforms that may be occurring using CSS `scale` property.

So I'm multiplying the offset by this:

```
* (angular.element('.bigTuna')[0].naturalHeight/angular.element('.bigTuna')[0].getBoundingClientRect().height);
```

The natural height divided by the height of the image. Importantly, this "height of the image" is derived from `getBoundingClientRect()` which means it takes CSS scaling into account.

So what is wrong with my logic here? I get crops all over the image, not in the coordinates I have specified.

**EDIT 4:**

I got the *very close* given the following equation, which I don't really understand (got from Croppie's source code)

```
var Xvalue = angular.element(".enclosedCrop")[0].getBoundingClientRect().left - angular.element(".bigTuna")[0].getBoundingClientRect().left + angular.element(".enclosedCrop")[0].offsetWidth + (angular.element(".enclosedCrop")[0].getBoundingClientRect().width - angular.element(".enclosedCrop")[0].offsetWidth) / 2;
var Yvalue = angular.element(".enclosedCrop")[0].getBoundingClientRect().top - angular.element(".bigTuna")[0].getBoundingClientRect().top + angular.element(".enclosedCrop")[0].offsetHeight + (angular.element(".enclosedCrop")[0].getBoundingClientRect().height - angular.element(".enclosedCrop")[0].offsetHeight) / 2;
Xvalue = parseFloat(Xvalue).toFixed(0);
Yvalue = parseFloat(Yvalue).toFixed(0);
```

However it is always a few pixels off, usually slightly down and to the right.

Can someone explain this equation so I can better edit it and find the mistake?

Comment: As an alternative, you can crop the image in the client side and send it already cropped to the server

Comment: I think you should only send x, y and image dimensions after scaling. From the image on the server you read its dimensions and then calculate the values you need. OT: Use `<canvas>` to generate image on client side.

Comment: @RomanCortes I would prefer to do the cropping on the server side.

Comment: @bato3 Can you explain more which data-points you suggest I send to server?

Comment: so you want to crop base on .enclosedCrop.small which this dynamic position and height, width?

Comment: @SummerDeveloper jquery facedetector you can show a little example and source and how to based jquery and facedetector. Regards.

Comment: you need send offset(x, y), size(width, height) and then can work with raw image and imagemagick

Comment: you want store circle image or square?

Answer (score 0):

This tricky part by css and js.

**Markup html**:

```
<div class="viewBox layer-image">
  <img class="bigTuna">
  <div class="enclosedCrop small"></div>
  <div class="overlay small"></div>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.layer-image {
  background-image: url('sample/image.png');
  position: relative;
  height: 800px; /* actual height sample*/
  weight: 800px; /* actual weight sample*/
}

.enclosedCrop.small {
  position: absolute;
}
```

We set class layer-image have background image and position as relative. well you know base absolute position is relative.

**Javascript**

Well for dragging, sizing you can use your favorite library or use own code. The big question is how to get x and y. If you see the code, we have already how to get x y. Imagine x y start from top left corner. So what just you need is get margin top of .enclosedCrop.small and margin left of .enclosedCrop.small from layer-image. for ex:

```
var offsetLayerBase = $('.enclosedCrop.small').offset();
var offsetCropping = $('.enclosedCrop.small').offset();
var yPositionCrop = offsetCropping.top - offsetLayerBase.top;
var xPositionCrop = offsetCropping.left - offsetLayerBase.left;
```

set `offsetLayerBase` as base from window (you need any custom if have css custom).

let me know if work for you. Cheers ;)

Comment: I know how to get the x and y again i have all the variables from my UI I just don't know how to translate to the server which just gets raw image and needs coordinates scaled to natural width and height.

Comment: @SummerDeveloper do you want to calculate on the client or the server?

Comment: if you see the demo, they use canvas for image (mostly), so I just thinking that use html 5 for calculate

Comment: and if you see on demo upload, it scale by image relative. sometimes fixed for height or weight. depends on portrait or landscape, I think. when you upload, it scaled. this is important 1st for positioning.